# Cancel down the fraction $\dfrac{(x-y)(\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[3]{y})}{\sqrt[3]{x^2}-\sqrt[3]{y^2}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

Cancel down the following fraction $$\dfrac{(x-y)(\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[3]{y})}{\sqrt[3]{x^2}-\sqrt[3]{y^2}}$$

I am not sure if cancel down means rationalize, so are we supposed to rationalize the given fraction or just cancel it down? How can we do just cancel it down?

Comment: $\sqrt[3]{x^2} - \sqrt[3]{y^2} = (\sqrt[3]{x} + \sqrt[3]{y})(\sqrt[3]{x} - \sqrt[3]{y})$. Hope this hint helps (using the identity $a^2-b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$)

Comment: You'll need to do a bit of both, and some factoring. It might be helpful to make a substitution of $u = \sqrt[3]{x}$ and $v = \sqrt[3]{y}$, so that the fraction becomes$$\frac{(u^3 - v^3)(u +v)}{u^2 - v^2}.$$Then, remember your difference of two cubes factorisation, as well as the difference of two squares pointed out by @Prometheus. You should find that you get lots of cancellation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the fact that $x^{\frac{2}{3}}=\left(x^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)^2$ , so as for $y$, we have:
$$x^{\frac{2}{3}}-y^{\frac{2}{3}}=\left(x^{\frac{1}{3}}-y^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)\cdot\left(x^{\frac{1}{3}}+y^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)$$
Plugging in, we have:
$$\dfrac{(x-y)(\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[3]{y})}{\left(x^{\frac{1}{3}}-y^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)\cdot\left(x^{\frac{1}{3}}+y^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)}=\frac{x-y}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}-y^{\frac{1}{3}}}$$
Then, you can observe:
$$x-y=\left(x^{\frac{1}{3}}-y^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)\cdot\left(x^{\frac{2}{3}}+(x\cdot y)^{\frac{1}{3}}+y^{\frac{2}{3}}\right)$$
So, finally:

$$\dfrac{(x-y)(\sqrt[3]{x}+\sqrt[3]{y})}{\sqrt[3]{x^2}-\sqrt[3]{y^2}}=\frac{\left(x^{\frac{1}{3}}-y^{\frac{1}{3}}\right)\cdot\left(x^{\frac{2}{3}}+(x\cdot y)^{\frac{1}{3}}+y^{\frac{2}{3}}\right)}{x^{\frac{1}{3}}-y^{\frac{1}{3}}}=\left(x^{\frac{2}{3}}+(x\cdot y)^{\frac{1}{3}}+y^{\frac{2}{3}}\right)$$

Comment: Please carefully read and review: [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?r=SearchResults&s=2|138.1095).

Answer (score 0):

I think fractional exponents are more intuitive than radicals.

$\frac {(x-y)(x^\frac 13 + y^\frac 13)}{x^\frac 23 - y^\frac23}$

We have a difference of squares in the denominator

$\frac {(x-y)(x^\frac 13 + y^\frac 13)}{(x^\frac 13 - y^\frac13)(x^\frac 13 + y^\frac13)}$

Giving us something to cancel.

$\frac {(x-y)}{(x^\frac 13 - y^\frac13)}$

We don't like radicals (or fractional roots) in the denominator but we can clean that up if we multiply top and bottom by the correct factor.

$\frac {(x-y)}{(x^\frac 13 - y^\frac13)}\frac{(x^\frac23 + x^\frac 13y^\frac 13 + y^\frac 23)}{(x^\frac23 + x^\frac 13y^\frac 13 + y^\frac 23)} = \frac {(x-y)(x^\frac23 + x^\frac 13y^\frac 13 + y^\frac 23)}{x-y} $

$x^\frac23 + x^\frac 13y^\frac 13 + y^\frac 23$ is as simple as I can get it.

Comment: Please review carefully, the following post: [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?r=SearchResults&s=2|138.1095).